# iFrame contents won't open in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe

Sometimes the browser war causes me to frown deeply when a simple piece of code refuses to work in one specific browser.

In this case I have an iframe that won't load in Google Chrome an I can't find out why. The url with the page that holds the iframe is: 
http://www.oit-harley-davidson.com/motoren/harley.html

Does anybody have an answer to this?

Grtz BartH

Comment: I would recommend posting your HTML in-line.

Answer (score 0):

As the console says:

```
Refused to display 'http://www.harley-davidson.com/nl_NL/Motorcycles/motorcycles.html' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Solution here:

[Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)